# Wildfly Swarm JAXRSArchive add webapp directory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, static-content, wildfly-swarm

I'm trying to add webapp folder with static HTML pages to JAXRSArchive with Wildfly Swarm. But unfortunately it was not successful. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all your static files in  `src/main/webapp`  and in you main method add the call `staticContenet` as follows

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Swarm container = new Swarm();
    JAXRSArchive jaxrsDeployment = ShrinkWrap.create(JAXRSArchive.class);
    jaxrsDeployment.addAsLibrary(container.createDefaultDeployment());
    jaxrsDeployment.addAllDependencies();
    jaxrsDeployment.staticContent();
    container.start();
    container.deploy(jaxrsDeployment);
```

Comment: I did the same thing, but it's not working for me. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: you could check the contents of the jar/war and see if they are adding properly

Comment: That's a problem. They do not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on why you need a custom main()?

The preferred option is to not use a custom main(), or if you must have a custom main() to not customize the deployment.

You can just call Swarm.deploy() and it will create a default deployment, which if your project is of type war, will work fine

Comment: I like Java based approach. And this deployment customization are used in most of wildfly-swarm examples(for example to add swagger). For me it's looks like better approach, but it's not well documented.

Comment: Most of the examples and documentation customize deployment, so it will not be much easier.

Comment: If you really need a custom main() because you need to customize the WAR in some way, use Swarm.createDefaultDeployment() to give you an Archive that is equivalent to Maven WAR packaging as opposed to constructing it all from scratch

Comment: @ken so how to make static html work with wilfdly swarm? I'm running into the same issue. I generated a project through http://wildfly-swarm.io/generator/ using JAX-RS and CDI. I didn't customize it. I tried to place htmls into `src/main/webapp`, tried `src/main/resources`, tried adding `web.xml` - still no lack. I also read the documentation and haven't found anything about this subject.

Answer (score 0):

This question is outdated. But I post this solution for those who run into the same issue.

The problem might happen if you're using `JAX-RS` without specifying `@ApplicationPath`.

By default JAX-RS listens to the root `/` of your app and overrides standard mapping.

In this case you have to add configuration like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JaxRSConfiguration extends Application {
}
```

This will prefix all your `JAX-RS` endpoints with `/api` and let you work with static content.